# How to make inherited base classes use a common variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, base-class

Let's say I want to create an interface for

1. `Item`s that have content that can be read.
2. `Item`s that have content that can be written.
3. `Item`s that have content that can be read a/o written

However I don't want to create 3 abstract classes as I may want to pass an `Item`, that is read-writable to a function which only accepts readable items.

e.g. you can only read a `Book`, so `Book` would inherit `Readable`, while a `Note` can be read and written, thus it would inherit `ReadWritable`.

So now I can create function like that:

```
std::string read(Readable& readable) const
```

or

```
void take_a_note(Writable& writable)
```

---

I have this `Readable` abstract class

```
template <typename ReadableType>
class Readable
{
public:
    Readable(const ReadableType content);
    virtual ~Readable(void);
    virtual auto content(void) const noexcept -> const ReadableType&&;

private:
    const ReadableType _content;
};
```

And a `Writable` abstract class

```
template <typename WritableType>
class Writable
{
public:
    Writable(void);
    virtual ~Writable(void);
    virtual void content(WritableType&& content) noexcept;

private:
    WritableType _content;
};
```

But now I want to create a an abstract class which combines those functionalities, called `ReadWritable`

```
template <typename ReadWritableType>
class ReadWritable: public Readable<ReadWritableType>, public Writable<ReadWritableType>
{
public:
    ReadWritable(ReadWritableType content);
    virtual ~ReadWritable(void);
    using Writable<ReadWritableType>::content;
    using Readable<ReadWritableType>::content;
};
```

This is where the problem is, as `content(WritableType&& content)` uses `Writable::_content`, while `content(void)` uses `Readable::_content`.

How I can make them use the same `_content` data member. And if I can do that, is there a way to delete the other one?

---

Or is my complete approach wrong? I'm open for every opinion.

Comment: I am not sure I got your question right - But have you had a look at the virtual base class concept? This would ensure there is only one _content member in your derived ReadWritable class

Comment: I thought this only applied if the Base Class is the exact same base, e.g. if I inherited Readable twice. The problem is not really that there's an overload, but that Readable::content() and Writable::content() each has their own private variable `_content` and they won't coordinate

Comment: Separate interface and implementation. The interface shouldn't store any state, and you should store all state in the implementation.

Comment: I dont think templates are the better usage for this case, yo dont want to create code for each specific redeable and writeable object, but your class expect to get an object that fullfills an interface, as mentioned by @tofro, you should check virtual classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got the question right but from my understanding you want to make two separate classes share same data and still continue their functionality with this shared data.

I have tested with several combination and the following code is working fine. However I had to make several changes:

```
#include <iostream>

class ReadableType
{
    public: int id=0;
            int* sharedValue;
};

class WritableType
{
    public: int id=1;
            int* sharedValue;
};

class ReadWritableType
{
    public: int id=2;
            int* sharedValue;
            ReadWritableType(int share){sharedValue = new int;*sharedValue = share;};
};

class Readable
{
public:
    void content(void){std::cout << "id: "<<_content->id <<" sharedValue: "<<*_content->sharedValue<<std::endl;};

protected:
    ReadableType *_content;
};


class Writable
{
public:
    void content(WritableType content){std::cout << "id: "<<_content->id <<" sharedValue: "<<*_content->sharedValue<<std::endl;};

protected:
    WritableType *_content;
};


class ReadWritable: public Readable, public Writable
{
public:
    ReadWritable(ReadWritableType* content);
    using Writable::content;
    using Readable::content;
private:
    void makeReadable(ReadWritableType* content);
    void makeWritable(ReadWritableType* content);
};

ReadWritable::ReadWritable(ReadWritableType* content)
{
    makeReadable(content);
    makeWritable(content);
}

void ReadWritable::makeReadable(ReadWritableType* content)
{
    Readable::_content = new ReadableType();
    Readable::_content->sharedValue = content->sharedValue;
}

void ReadWritable::makeWritable(ReadWritableType* content)
{
    Writable::_content = new WritableType();
    Writable::_content->sharedValue = content->sharedValue;
}
int main()
{
    ReadWritable x(new ReadWritableType(5));
    WritableType s;
    x.content();
    x.content(s);   
}
```

The output is that each _content is using a private value (id) and a shared value (sharedValue) which shares the same memory between two _contents.

Answer (score 1):

With an extra layer, you may do

```
template <typename ReadableType>
class IReadable
{
public:
    virtual ~IReadable() = default;
    virtual const ReadableType& content() const noexcept = 0;
};

template <typename WritableType>
class IWritable
{
public:
    virtual ~IWritable();
    virtual void content(WritableType&& content) noexcept = 0;
};

template <typename ReadableType>
class Readable : public IReadable
{
public:
    Readable(const ReadableType& content);
    virtual const ReadableType& content() const noexcept override;
private:
    const ReadableType _content;
};

template <typename WritableType>
class Writable
{
public:
    virtual void content(WritableType&& content) noexcept override;
private:
    WritableType _content;
};
```

And finally:

```
template <typename ReadWritableType>
class ReadWritable: public IReadable<ReadWritableType>, public IWritable<ReadWritableType>
{
public:
    ReadWritable(ReadWritableType content);

    virtual void content(WritableType&& content) noexcept override;
    virtual const ReadableType& content() const noexcept override;
private:
    ReadWritableType _content;
};
```

You have indeed to reimplement `ReadWritable::content`, but code may be factorized with `Readable`/`Writable` one and reused.